# Issue with event handler and FlexLayout in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm encountering a puzzling issue with MAUI involving FlexLayout. I have a setup where I use a FlexLayout to display dynamic content, and I noticed some unexpected behavior.

I have a layout structure like this:

```
<FlexLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White" AlignContent="Center" Direction="Column">
    <Label x:Name="titlePage" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="10,5,0,0"/>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="DarkGray" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
    <FlexLayout x:Name="ReglagesFlexLayout" Direction="Column" AlignContent="Center" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
        <!-- Dynamic elements to be modified -->
    </FlexLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

When I initialize the page with the following code, everything works as expected:

```
public ParametersPage(ParametersPageViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    titlePage.Text = "General";
    GeneralBoxView.IsVisible = true;
    GeneralButton.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "Text";
    label.FontSize = 50;

    ReglagesFlexLayout.Children.Add(label);
}
```

However, when I handle a button click event with the following code, it seems to enter the "General" case of the switch case statement but doesn't display the expected content:

```
private void OnParameterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button clickedButton)
    {
        // Handling button clicks
        switch (clickedButton.Text)
        {
            case "General":
                ReglagesFlexLayout.Children.Clear();

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = "Text";
                label.FontSize = 50;

                ReglagesFlexLayout.Children.Add(label);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Despite entering the "General" case, the content doesn't appear as expected. Can anyone help me understand why the initialization code works fine but the event handler doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have successfully resolved the issue. I have made adjustments to my layout structure, replacing the FlexLayout with a ContentView:

```
<ContentView Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             AlignContent="Center"
             Direction="Column">
    <Label x:Name="titlePage"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
           Margin="10,5,0,0"/>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="DarkGray" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
    <ContentView x:Name="ParametersView">
        
    </ContentView>
</ContentView>
```

Additionally, I have created a dedicated view for each possible option, and I've implemented the following method to handle updates:

```
private void UpdateParametersView(string choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case "General":
        default:
            ParametersView.Content = new GeneralSettingsView();
            break;
    }
}
```

This approach allows me to dynamically change the content of the ParametersView based on the selected option.